# How to apply style sheets separately to specific components in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

In my current project, I'm loading separate style files (a.css, b.css, c.css) that are only used for specific components in index.html as shown below, all using link tags.

```
<head>
  <link href="assets/css/a.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/b.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/c.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

The style.css for applying common styles is set in angular.json.

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "styles": ["src/styles.css", "src/developers.css", "src/assets/common.css"],
           }
          }
```

The problem is that with the above setup, all CSS is downloaded on the first page load. Files A,B,C are files that should only be applied to certain components on certain pages.

Like below I've tried styling them separately using styleUrls in the ts file for that component, but the styles don't apply.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text-editor',
  styleUrls: ['./a.css', './b.css', './c.css'],
})
```

Also, styling with the LINK tag in the HTML file of that component didn't work well either.

I would like to know how to apply a global style by default, but additionally apply a specific style file only when a specific component is rendered.

Comment: Import the SCSS (via @import) directly in the component that requires it?